# rabbitmq - does not get all messages in the queue

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am trying to play around with rabbitmq with this tutorial(https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/) and i am not sure why i am not getting all the messages at once.

Code snippets:

Runner.java

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
private final Receiver receiver;
private final ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

public Runner(Receiver receiver, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Sending message...");
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.queueName, "Hello from 1");
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.queueName, "Hello from 2");
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.queueName, "Hello from 3");
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.queueName, "Hello from 4");
   // receiver.getLatch().await(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    context.close();
}

}
```

Receiver.java

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Component
public class Receiver implements MessageListener{

private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);


@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
    latch.countDown();
}

public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
    return latch;
}

}
```

Application.java

```
package hello;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;



import hello.Receiver;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

final static String queueName = "spring-boot";

@Bean
@Qualifier("pubsubQueue")
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, true, false, false);
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("eventExchange")
FanoutExchange exchange() {
    return new FanoutExchange("spring-boot-exchange",false,false);
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("pubsubQueueBinding")
Binding binding(@Qualifier("pubsubQueue") Queue queue,@Qualifier("eventExchange") FanoutExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange);
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        Receiver receiver,@Qualifier("pubsubQueue") Queue queue) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueues(queue);
    //container.setQueueNames(queueName);
    container.setMessageListener(receiver);
    return container;
}




public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}







}
```

My output would sometime return 2 msgs, sometime 3 and sometime 4. How do i make sure i get all the 4 msgs every time. Thanks and appreciate your help.

Sample outputs:

```
Test Run 1 : 
  Hello from 1 
  Hello from 2 
Test Run 2 : 
  Hello from 3 
  Hello from 4 
  Hello from 1 
  Hello from 2 
  Hello from 3 
Test Run 3: 
  Hello from 4 
  Hello from 1 
  Hello from 2 
  Hello from 3 

Expected output(all the time)
  Hello from 1 
  Hello from 2
  Hello from 3 
  Hello from 4
```

Comment: Which ones are you seeing when you only get 2? 1 & 2 or 3 & 4? It's best to show your complete app for questions like this, rather than snippets so we don't have to guess. Edit the question to show all classes or, even better, post the whole project to GiHub.

Comment: @GaryRussell : Thanks for the reply , Gary. I updated the question to include all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.close();
```

You are closing the application context immediately after you send the 4 messages; closing the context stops the listener container.

You need to wait until they are all received; you have a latch, but the `await()` is commented out and the latch is only initialized at 1; needs to be 4.